# Access to IP Camera using VPN to Webserver for Public IP

Tags: vpn, tunneling

I'm tasked with setting up access to IP cameras in remote construction sites in the Philippines.
The internet access is provided via Ubiquiti Power Beam from the only supplier available in the area. They have 6 or 7 levels of NAT and only basic load balancing between their providers there's no possible dedicated IP addresses and they can't reconfigure their network to allow remote access to the cameras.

It's my hope we could set up a VPN tunnel from the LAN with the cameras to a public web server (running some VPN software), allowing remote users to connect to the public web server IP address to be routed to the cameras on the LAN.

Possibly a separate port for each camera and no more than 3 cameras per site. This tunnel would hardly be used at all with only an occasional connection from a single remote viewer in the event of an alert being sent.

Is this even possible? What software/packages are recommended? What terminology should I be using for this type of setup?
And of course: Is there an easier way with the existing infrastructure?

Any info much appreciated.

Comment: It's extremely frightening that they aren't using IPv6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton With 6 or 7 levels of NAT that would be a little tricky don't you think? "Extremely frightening" Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main solution for such scenarios is a reverse-connection. As the service(s) (cameras in your case) are not accessible directly, you have to make a tunnel/connection from that private network back to a public server of yours, to which users have access. The idea is to make a mapping like:

```
PublicServer:PortX <==> CameraLANServer:PortX <==> Camera1:80
PublicServer:PortY <==> CameraLANServer:PortY <==> Camera2:80
PublicServer:PortZ <==> CameraLANServer:PortZ <==> Camera3:80
```

where CameraLANServer must be default gateway for the cameras and must connect back to public server using any available tunneling protocol, SOCKS proxy or SSH port forwarding, and the ports X,Y,Z to be available (opened on its firewall).

Packet/Port Forwarding must also be activated and configured on PublicServer towards the incoming connection/tunnel from CameraLANServer. (details depends on the platforms e.g. Windows, Linux, ... used at each side)

Comment: That looks like what I need but I don't know how to go about setting it up. I believe I will need to initiate a tunnel from the `CameraLANServer` to the `PublicServer` and setup appropriate firewall rules to forward traffic arriving at port X on the `PublicServer` back across the VPN to the `CameraLanServer` and on to the camera. If you could point me in the direction of a similar tutorial I should be ok now I know it's possible.

Comment: @Tajbakhsh  I think I found what I need now, thanks for the heads up on the terminology, searched for `reverse VPN`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7qr0laM8kA